# Horizontal Recyclerview with scrollable header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement an android horizontal recyclerview like the image shown below.[image: Both week block and day block needs to be scrolled at the same time]

Both week block and day block needs to be scrolled at the same time. After day 14 another week have to come. So to make both blocks scroll at the same time I imagine it needs to be in the same recyclerview. I have implemented the day recyclerview. But I don't know how to implement the week block. Week block needs to be of the 7-day block size. How do I do that?

Comment: Why dont you use view pager with one page consits of week1 and and their 7 days?

Comment: you can create two view in recyclerView adpater and set it in single adpater  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: Refer This : https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Answer (score 0):

For this, I'd recommend a horizontal `GridLayoutManager` with two rows.  Since the week is exactly 7 days, you can use a span size of 7 for the weeks, and 1 for the days.